# why jw player wont be fullscreen?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwplayer

I have a problem with JW player. when I touch fullscreen button in JW player nothing happen and just arrow state change. and when I rotate phone JW become from vertical to horizontal but won't be fullscreen. I check my another app that worked in JW player previously but now they won't work too. (JW can play video without any problem but can't be in fullscreen in no way).
may please help me with this?

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        if (newConfig?.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if(jw.fullscreen) {
                jw.setFullscreen(false, true)
            }
        } else if (newConfig?.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            if(!jw.fullscreen) {
                jw.setFullscreen(true, true)
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my code that controls change rotation in JW player.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android 9, you will need to update the JWPlayer SDK at least to 3.4.1 (there was fixed).

Here you can find the answer:
[Android - JWplayer Fullscreen not working issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032362/android-jwplayer-fullscreen-not-working-issue)