# Android - JWplayer Fullscreen not working issue

Tags: android, jwplayer

I've just implemented JWPlayer for Android and realise that the fullscreen button on the player is not working.

I've also realise that the the method:

```
JWPlayerView.setFullscreen(true, true)
```

Does not work (the video doesn't go fullscreen, just stay in portrait video).

I'm on JWPlayer version 3.4.0.

Also there is an error thrown by JWPlayer when requesting fullscreen when fullscreen button is pressed:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 
fullscreen error", source: 
http://intercept.jw//data/user/0/com.knx.thestarmobile/files/jwplayer/jw_co
re/jwplayer.core.controls.js (10)
```

Wondering if anyone is facing this issue as well and if there are any solutions to this.

Edit:

I've also tried this with the samples app provided by JWPlayer and the same issue happens.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 3.4.1. This issue is fixed now.

Comment: How about JWPlayer SDK 2.x ? $6000 for a fullscreen bugfix is a little expensive don't you think ?

Comment: I have implemented this in react native. Even there it is not working. Please let us know if anybody fix this.